# SQL query: reaction of one table/time-series on another, for each user

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

Suppose I have tables `A` and `B`, both with over 100 million rows containing 8 years worth of data. They both have columns `row_id` (=unique row identifier, e.g. row number), `person_id`, `dt` (=datetime). A row in `A` represents a time when a user opened an email message. A row in `B` represents a time a user visited a specific website.

I wish to create a table `C`, which is exactly `A` with a few (let's say 10) columns `C_i` appended. These columns `C_i` must measure, after a user opened an email (i.e. in a row in A), how many times (in a time-interval of `i`  hours after opening the email) he visited the website (i.e. a count of a few rows in `B`). How can I efficiently construct `C`?

My attempt, in Oracle PL/SQL, for adding just one column `C_1`:

```
SELECT 
    any_value(A.id), 
    any_value(A.person_id), 
    any_value(A.dt), 
    count(1) response_1h 
FROM A, B 
WHERE 
    A.person_id = B.person_id AND 
    0 <= B.dt - A.dt AND B.dt-A.dt<=1/24 
GROUP BY A.row_id;
```

I am getting an error (not for this but for a similar query), I suspect because of joining tables that are too large:

> ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 256 in tablespace TEMP_DEV
> 01652. 00000 -  "unable to extend temp segment by %s in tablespace %s"
> *Cause:    Failed to allocate an extent of the required number of blocks for
> a temporary segment in the tablespace indicated.
> *Action:   Use ALTER TABLESPACE ADD DATAFILE statement to add one or more
> files to the tablespace indicated.

Doing it this way for 10 new columns seems far from optimal. Would anyone care to tell me how this is done properly?

Comment: If a user opened a message at 10:00 and then another at 10:10 and then they visited a website at 10:30, do you count 0 or 1 response_1h for the first message?

Comment: What is the current query plan?  Do both tables have indexes on `(person_id,dt)`?  You'd want to structure your date comparisons so that at least one of those two indexes could be used.  Assuming your logic is correct, doing something like `a.dt <= b.dt and b.dt <= a.dt + interval '1' hour`  would allow Oracle to use the compound index on `b` which is what I'd guess you'd want.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner If one user opens two messages, one at 10:00 (row `i` in `A`) and one at 10:10 (row `j` in `A`), and visits the website only once between 10:00-11:10, namely at 10:30, then in `C.response_1h`, both row `i` and `j` should have value 1., because in both cases, in the 1h-interval after the email was opened, the website was visited exactly once.

Comment: @Leo: This makes it easier. It would have been much harder otherwise. With 100M rows in each table, the query will probably run very long. Writing it, on the other hand, is not that difficult :-) I've posted two options in my answer.

Comment: @JustinCave The query `SELECT * FROM all_indexes WHERE table_name='A'` returned an empty table, so I think there are no indexes on the columns of my `A` and `B`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can count the website access with conditional aggregation. Below examples looks at the ten hours after each message and count conditionally.

```
select
  a.id, a.person_id, a.dt,
  count(case when b.dt <= a.dt + interval '1' hour then 1 end) as response_1h,
  count(case when b.dt <= a.dt + interval '2' hour then 1 end) as response_2h,
  count(case when b.dt <= a.dt + interval '3' hour then 1 end) as response_3h,
  count(case when b.dt <= a.dt + interval '4' hour then 1 end) as response_4h,
  count(case when b.dt <= a.dt + interval '5' hour then 1 end) as response_5h,
  count(case when b.dt <= a.dt + interval '6' hour then 1 end) as response_6h,
  count(case when b.dt <= a.dt + interval '7' hour then 1 end) as response_7h,
  count(case when b.dt <= a.dt + interval '8' hour then 1 end) as response_8h,
  count(case when b.dt <= a.dt + interval '9' hour then 1 end) as response_9h,
  count(b.dt) as response_10h
from a
left join b on b.person_id = a.person_id
            and b.dt > a.dt
            and b.dt <= a.dt + interval '10' hour
group by a.id, a.person_id, a.dt
order by a.id;
```

The same with a lateral join instead:

```
select *
from a
outer apply 
(
  select 
    count(case when b.dt <= a.dt + interval '1' hour then 1 end) as response_1h,
    count(case when b.dt <= a.dt + interval '2' hour then 1 end) as response_2h,
    count(case when b.dt <= a.dt + interval '3' hour then 1 end) as response_3h,
    count(case when b.dt <= a.dt + interval '4' hour then 1 end) as response_4h,
    count(case when b.dt <= a.dt + interval '5' hour then 1 end) as response_5h,
    count(case when b.dt <= a.dt + interval '6' hour then 1 end) as response_6h,
    count(case when b.dt <= a.dt + interval '7' hour then 1 end) as response_7h,
    count(case when b.dt <= a.dt + interval '8' hour then 1 end) as response_8h,
    count(case when b.dt <= a.dt + interval '9' hour then 1 end) as response_9h,
    count(b.dt) as response_10h
  from b 
  where b.person_id = a.person_id
    and b.dt > a.dt
    and b.dt <= a.dt + interval '10' hour
)
order by a.id;
```

Look at the explain plans to see whether one is supposed to run faster than the other.

For either query you want a composite index on table b in order to find its matching rows quickly. As the order of the columns in the index should matter, I'd add both possible indexes:

```
create index idx1 on b (person_id, dt);
create index idx2 on b (dt, person_id);
```

You can always drop an index that is not being used.

As to ORA-01652: I cannot answer this. Maybe you can just increase the size of the temp tablespace and be done with the problem. I don't know.

Comment: Thank you @ThorstenKettner, give me a bit of time to try out your approach before I accept your answer.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. But if the intention is to fill another table with it, then the `ORDER BY` isn't really needed. Without sorting it'll probably be a bit faster and require less temp tablespace.

Comment: If `A` contains many additional columns that I wish to keep, is it possible to retain them using a simpler method than just listing all of them? Something like `SELECT any_value(A.*), ... FROM A LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON ... GROUP BY A.row_id`?

Comment: For the first query there is no simpler way. In standard SQL it suffices to group by the primary key (a.id) in order to `select a.*`. In Oracle, though, you must either have all columns in `GROUP BY` or aggregate them. But in the second query table a is not aggregated, so `select a.*` is no problem. So you see, I've already shown you the sinpler method; it's the second query.

Comment: Thank you, your query finished successfully after 3h. Just one more thing: aren't there too many `)`'s each time after `hour`, or too few `(`'s?

Comment: Yes, of course, the closing parentheses don't belong. Sorry about that. I've removed them now. Glad this worked for you.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: You have provided both indexes and ran the second query? Can you tell us which of the two indexes got used?

Comment: At the moment, I do not have write/edit privileges on the database, so I ran both your queries without indexes. The first approach required 145min, the second needed 44min. : )

Comment: Ah, okay, thank you. Without indexes and such big tables this is a lot of work for the DBMS. Great that it didn't time out :-) The second query may have been faster, because of a better execution plan or just because it was run after the other and there was still data in some cache the DBMS could use again.